# SonarLint.Runner.exe is missing on TFS Build

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Since a while the SonarQube step on my build process is failing. The Error tells me

```
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\TFS_Agents\_work\1\.********qube\out\.********\SonarLint.Runner\SonarLint.Runner.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
...
```

So I checked the path and there are all files except the SonarLint.Runner.exe. Even the SonarLint.Runner.exe.config file is there.
First our BitDefender put the .exe file in quarantine but we set it on the whitelist and everthing should be fine. Even if we set BitDefender off, it is sill missing on the build process, so the build fails.

Does anyone have this problem behavior?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Howe's your build definition like?

Comment: I'm running on TFS 2017 with Sonar Qube 5.1.2. This is my build definition: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170227/sr8ez2py.png It's german but I think you will get it

Answer (score 0):

The two tasks which are deprecated are the SonarQube for MSBuild tasks (SonarQube for ‘MSBuild – Begin Analysis’ and ‘SonarQube for MSBuild – End Analysis’). You would need to install [the SonarQube extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) and use the three new tasks in your library:

[image]

Useful links:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/12/13/sonarsource-have-announced-their-own-sonarqube-team-services-tfs-integration/
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

Comment: I'm running on TFS 2017 with Sonar Qube Version 5.1.2. There is no option now to update to a newer version. Is it still possible to use the old SonarQube tasks or are they totally deprecated (like you can't use them anymore)? With the new tasks I need a authentication token wich is only possible on SonarQube 5.6+

Comment: On my test with Sonar Qube Version 6.0, the old SonarQube Tasks still work. Make sure the .NET Framework v4.5.2+ and Java Runtime Environment v7u75+ are installed.

Comment: The .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Java JDK and JRE are 8u121 but still the same problem

Comment: You may consider upgrading your SonarQube server.